# How in Ant output values of properties?

Tags: ant, echo, default-value

With `ant` there exists the `echo` markup:

```
<echo message="Hello, world"/>
```

but it seems useless. I need to check values in an ant script, e.g.

```
 <property file="${user.home}/build.properties"/>
 <echo message="${file}" />
```

but it only yields:

```
 [echo] ${file}
```

How I can have Ant display the value of the `file` property?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This statement:

```
<property file="${user.home}/build.properties"/>
```

[Reads a property file](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)(i.e. all properties in that file), and does not set the property named **file**.

This would be correct. You first set a property and then echo it:

```
<property name="file" value="${user.home}/build.properties"/>
<echo message="${file}" />
```

Answer (score 8):

You're getting `${file}` echoed back at you because you're not setting that property. Is there a line in your property file that says `file = someValue`?

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
<property name="property.file" value="${user.home}/build.properties"/>
<property file="${property.file}"/>
<echo message="My property file is called &quot;${property.file}&quot;"/>
```